# Why no return object when I add a tag dynamically?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

[image]

The selected "tr" tag is added dynamically by a click event, but this  cannot return anything by another click event. All original static "tr" tags which are above the dynamically added "tr" can return normally by same click event.

```
// eventhandler to get current this<tr> object
$('tr').click(function () {
                    console.log(this)
}
//original static <tr>, works fine
<tr>
                    <td>Meet friends for dinner</td>
                    <td><time datetime="2013-10-14">2013-10-14</time></td>
                    <td>Personal</td>
                    <td>
                        <nav>
                            <a href="#">Edit</a>
                            <a href="#">Complete</a>
                            <a href="#">Delete</a>
                        </nav>
                    </td>
</tr>
//how I add <tr> dynamically
<script id="taskRow" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
<tr>
    <td>${task}</td>
    <td><time datetime="${requiredBy}">${requiredBy}</time></td>
    <td>${category}</td>
    <td>
        <nav>
            <a href='#'>Edit</a>
            <a href='#'>Complete</a>
            <a href='#' class='deleteRow'>Delete</a>

        </nav>
     </td>
</tr>
</script>
```

Comment: Please show your code so we can help

Comment: please see image in the "enter image description here"

Comment: @hei [Images of code are not acceptable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Please copy paste your code in the question directly instead

Comment: My crystal Ball is at repair, you have to show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .click()

Thus in your following code `tr` must exist before the code is generated.

```
$('tr').click(function () {
  console.log(this);
}
```

If new HTML is being injected into the page, it is preferable to use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.

**Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

```
$("table").on("click", "tr", function(event){
    console.log(this);
});
```

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pp3vsofx/) for more information.

**NOTE:** A delegated-events approach (the second code example) attaches an event handler to only one element, the `table`, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked `tr` to `table`).

Comment: Hi Kamal, you are correct, but I got another issue. The 'tr' now returns object and can toggleClass when I click, but the CSS style did not apply to these 'tr' with classname'rowHighlight'. Thanks!
 $('table').on('click','tr',function (evt) {
                        console.log($(this))
                        $(this).toggleClass('rowHighlight');
                    })